# what are the methods to convert negative values of matrix into positive?

Tags: matlab, matrix, negative-number

I want to convert the negative value of matrix into positive for model order reduction in matlab software .So,for conversion of negative values into positive there are different methods like trigonometric functions, absolute ,mode ,squaring and other than this any technique or method to convert negative value into positive ???? please suggest

Thank you

Comment: Yes, MATLAB provides an absolute function, [`abs(x)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html).

Comment: @mimocha yes but other than this any new method to convert negative value into positive????

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @shabana Please explain what do you mean by "new" method? What exactly are you looking for? Why isn't the absolute, squaring or any other method working for you? What have you tried so far? Without these information, this question is too vague.

Comment: @mimocha actually i am doing model reduction in control system and in control system for stable model you have to convert negative value into positive to make it positive definite matrix ,as these methods have been used already so i cannot use these methods to improve the result it is mandatory to use new method.may be now got it ???? i am doing thesis on model order reduction ...thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something different than using the abs function, have you tried running through all entries in the matrix, checking if they are less than 0, and then multiplying the ones that are by -1?

```
for i = 1:length(matrix)
    if matrix(i) < 0
        matrix(i) = matrix(i) * -1;
    end
end
```

Would be visually easier to read and simpler to understand just using the abs function, but if you're deadset on using something else, you can try this

Comment: thank you i will try this as i was only considering multiplying with -1. other than this any method you suggest please????

Comment: actually i am doing model reduction in control system and in control system for stable model you have to convert negative value into positive to make it positive definite matrix ,as these methods have been used already so i cannot use these methods to improve the result it is mandatory to use new method.???? i am doing thesis on model order reduction ...thank you